# Convert matrix to tuples

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I generate a sequence of values, tile them by the range provided and then increment each value in each row by that current row ID, then mask some values outside of a desired range like below:

```
>>> range = 5
>>> matrix = np.arange(-5, 10, 1)
>>> matrix = np.tile(matrix, (range, 1))
>>> matrix = np.add(matrix, np.arange(0, range)[:, None])
>>> matrix = ma.masked_outside(matrix, 0, 10)
[[-- -- -- -- -- 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
 [-- -- -- -- 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
 [-- -- -- 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 --]
 [-- -- 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 -- --]
 [-- 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 -- -- --]]
```

How would you best convert the above output to a matrix of the format `[non-masked value, row-id]`, i.e.:

```
[0,0], [1, 0], [2,0] ... [10, 4]
```

Also, is the original code too wasteful to achieve the final desired step?

Comment: Don't forget to add the more important python tag, otherwise you'll miss most of your target audience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing around with your `matrix` I produced this:

```
In [50]: np.stack((matrix.compressed(), np.where(~matrix.mask)[0]),1)
Out[50]: 
array([[ 0,  0],
       [ 1,  0],
       [ 2,  0],
       [ 3,  0],
       [ 4,  0],
       [ 5,  0],
       [ 6,  0],
       [ 7,  0],
       [ 8,  0],
       [ 9,  0],
      ....
```

We could probably skip the masked array step, creating the `mask` directly.  The `compressed` for example is produced by `matrix.data[~matrix.mask]`.

```
In [52]: mask = ~matrix.mask
In [53]: data = matrix.data
In [54]: np.stack((data[mask], np.where(mask)[0]), 1)
```